# How to mimic Camera app - Override orientation change animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, animation, uikit

I am trying to create a view controller very similar to Apple's Camera app. Notice how the bottom bar stays stuck to the home button no matter how you turn the phone. Individual elements rotate and move around in response, but 
the main view stays in place.

How can I re-create this?

[image: iOS Camera App Portrait]
<sub>(source: [gcflearnfree.org](http://content.gcflearnfree.org/topics/230/2013_camera_orient_por.jpg))</sub>

[iOS Camera App Lanscape http://content.gcflearnfree.org/topics/230/2013_camera_orient_lan.jpg](http://content.gcflearnfree.org/topics/230/2013_camera_orient_lan.jpg)

If I enable orientations for my view, there's a big distracting animation as the whole view rotates around. I need things to stay in place.

I've tried disabling orientation changes in my view, and animating everything by hand, but I need to present a UIAlertController, and the alert appears upside down or sideways if you've rotated the phone.

Is there some way to allow orientation changes, but make the animation happen instantly? Then I could move elements to their new positions at the same time and they would appear to hold still.

If not, how would you re-create the orientation and layout behavior of the iOS Camera app?

Comment: Have you looked at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1890/_index.html?

Comment: No, that's great, thank you! I think I have a simpler solution though, I'll post below.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution scraped together from various other questions:

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)

    let duration = coordinator.transitionDuration()
    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, animations: {
        // things you want to animate go here
        // any animations we kick off before turning them off will continue
    })

    // prevent any animations until this completes
    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
    coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition({ context in

    }, completion: { context in
        // turn animations back on. 
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
    })
}
```